# How to drive two motors using LEGO TechnicHub by LEGO Wireless Protocol

Tags: bluetooth, lego-mindstorms

I try to drive two motors.
Using a protocol at 6.3.3. Port Synchronization, I think I can drive two motors.
According to 6.3.3., Virtual port ID is 100.

So, I think I can drive motors using that ID.But I can't.
Please teach me how to program.